# How to remove js ui library added by default by wordpress

Tags: plugins, jquery, hooks

I am trying to remove some script files added by wordpress. However, the code I wrote does not work. Where am I doing wrong? Can you show me the way?

I looked at many sources. But I couldn't find an answer for the ui. I have used the wp_dequeue_script function many times. But it doesn't work for Wordpress.

child theme function.php

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'a_remove_some_js'); 
function a_remove_some_js() { 
     //wp_dequeue_script( 'jquery-ui-core-js');
    //wp_dequeue_script( 'jquery-ui-tooltip-js');
    wp_dequeue_script( 'jquery-ui-core');
    wp_dequeue_script( 'jquery-ui-tooltip');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The related library is registered with a function called [wp_default_scripts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_default_scripts/).
File location (for Wordpress 6.0): **...[wp-includes/script-loader.php](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/df0d9100070579ef83b4acd0db865232d4a0e58a/wp-includes/script-loader.php#L1446)**
remove to remove the relevant script; The add function is used to add a new script.

```
/**
 * Assigns default styles to $styles object.
 *
 * Nothing is returned, because the $styles parameter is passed by reference.
 * Meaning that whatever object is passed will be updated without having to
 * reassign the variable that was passed back to the same value. This saves
 * memory.
 *
 * Adding default styles is not the only task, it also assigns the base_url
 * property, the default version, and text direction for the object.
 *
 * @since 2.6.0
 *
 * @global array $editor_styles
 *
 * @param WP_Styles $styles
 */


add_action( 'wp_default_scripts', 'remove_js_ui_library' );
function remove_js_ui_library( &$scripts){
    if(!is_admin()){
        $scripts->remove( 'jquery-ui-core');
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It is add_action, not a filter hook - @ddisdevelpgelis

You added it as a filter hook in below code

```
add_filter( 'wp_default_scripts', 'remove_js_ui_library' );
function remove_js_ui_library( &$scripts){
    if(!is_admin()){
        $scripts->remove( 'jquery-ui-core');
    }
}
```

My changes to the above code :

```
add_action( 'wp_default_scripts', 'remove_js_ui_library' );
function remove_js_ui_library( &$scripts){
    if(!is_admin()){
        $scripts->remove( 'jquery-ui-core');
    }
}
```

Checkout this link for more information - [wp_default_scripts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_default_scripts/)